# Memory leak with material theme

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary, material-design

Currently I installed leakcanary to track a memory leak in my application. After starting my application I get following log from leakcanary from many of my actvities.

> GC ROOT android.service.theme.MaterialThemeManager$1.this$0 (anonymous class extends android.service.theme.IOnMaterialThemeChangedListener$Stub)
>   05-31 16:14:57.240 19260-20575/in.moovo.Moovo D/LeakCanary: * references android.service.theme.MaterialThemeManager.mContext
>   05-31 16:14:57.240 19260-20575/in.moovo.Moovo D/LeakCanary: * references android.app.ContextImpl.mOuterContext

how can I solve this memory leak and what causing this leak.